# Error of ssl certificate while integrating instamojo payment gateway in php

Tags: php, codeigniter, ssl, curl

When I was trying to integrate instamojo php payment gateway in codeigniter on local machine I keep on getting following error message

> "Error: Something went wrong. cURL raised an error with number: 77 and
>   message: error setting certificate verify locations: CAfile:
>   C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\bin\cacert.pem CApath: none."

I research a lot but I didn't find any setting to set SSL_verfifer false in instamojo php payment api. Need a bit of assistance on it.

Answer (score 0):

In Instamojo API just change this to false in line number 95

`$options[CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER] = false;`